# Vue Render Functions and Vuetify ui components

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, render

Is it possible to use a `vuetify uicomponent` like `v-app-var`, `v-navigation-drawer`, etc. within `Vue` render functions:

```js
render(createElement) {
    return createElement('v-app-bar', {}, )
```

Comment: Probably. Have you tried it?

Comment: I did, sorry for not posting the code.  The issue is that if you are using render within a vue component, the vuetify uicomponents are not found.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for example you could render the `v-app-bar` and its contents like..

```
render(createElement){
  const icon = createElement('v-app-bar-nav-icon')
  const spacer = createElement('v-spacer')
  const iconBtn = createElement('v-icon', 'mdi-heart')
  const btn = createElement('v-btn', [iconBtn])
  return createElement('v-app-bar', [
    icon, spacer, btn
  ])
},
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/mWDDrjgKj1

Comment: Thx, the reference to the Vuetify plugin 'vuetify: new Vuetify()' doesn't work if you are in a component, within the export default block, 'export default { vuetify: new Vuetify,...}'.  Can this only be done at the point when a new Vue instance is being defined?

Comment: I have posted a clarifying question that I this is within a standalone vue component.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference:

You simply have to import it manually into the vue component.

```
<script>
import { VAppBar } from "vuetify/lib";

export default {
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(VAppBar, {});
  },
};
</script>
```

More info at this [link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#manually-importing).